# Prove that the set of all infinite monotone sequences of {0, 1, 2} is countable

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have the following problem for my homework:

Prove that the following set $A$ is countable: $A$ consists of all infinite sequences, $a_0, a_1,...$ that are monotone and such that for every $i = 0, 1,...,a_i \in \{0,1,2\}$.

I am honestly not sure where to start. Some guidance would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Countable means finite or countably infinite (there are the same number of them as natural numbers, we can "count" them). You need to show a bijection between $A$ and the natural numbers.

Comment: @DanielP That is precisely the issue--I am familiar with the definition of countability, but I'm not sure where to get started on constructing such a bijection.

Comment: Sounds fun. I would start by writing a handful of (initial segments of) sequences that satisfy the requirements. This should spark some ideas - you want to become convinced that there cannot be very "many" sequences of this type. For a formal proof, it would be hard to produce one out of nowhere; you might need to find some ideas from other proofs of countability.

Comment: That's good! At least you know what to do! Monote means it's monotonically increasing or decreasing. So any sequence in $A$ will look something like $0,0,0,\dots,0,1,1,1,\dots,1,2,2,2,\dots$, or the reverse; maybe without one or multiple of the digits appearing. For example it could just be a string of $1$'s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know the union of two countable sets is countable. So we can break down the monotone sequences into more manageable pieces. For example we consider all sequences of the form $$0,0,0,\ldots,0,1,1,1\ldots,1,2,2,2,2,2,\ldots.$$ There are countable positions in the sequence that can change from $1$ to $2$, and for each of those cases, there are finitely many more choices to pick the point $0$ to $1$. So because countable union of countable sets is countable, there are countably many sequences of this form. The rest cases follow similarly.

In fact, by a similar argument, you can prove that are countably many decreasing sequences in $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Thank you! Just to make sure I'm understanding your answer right, the reason the set is countable is because you can construct an infinite number of finite, and therefore countable, sets from the set. This is because there is a finite number of operations (flipping a 1 to a 2 or a 0 to a 1) on the sequence. Then, the set is countable because the union of countable sets is countable. 
Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, not only an infinite number of finite sets, but also countably infinitely many finite sets.

Answer (score 1):

Map each monotonically increasing sequence which contains all three of the digits to the pair of integers $(x,y)$ where $x$ and $y$ are respectively the number of $0$s and $1$s in the sequence. So these are countable.

Similarly for the other few possibilities.

Comment: Not quite.  It's not necessarily true that $y$ is an integer.  The sequence could consist entirely of $1$s, for instance.  It's an easy fix, of course.

Comment: Yes, good point. Thanks @Robert Shore.